# How to format text with RxJava + RxAndroid WidgetObservable

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have an edittext where user enters some amount, I have a continue button which is disabled by default and is only enabled if the amount is valid and within some range,Everything works fine until I try to format the amount as $2000 or $10,000.   Here is how I am using WidgetObservable on an edit text.

```
Observable<Boolean> amountValidObervable = WidgetObservable.text(amount, false)
            .debounce(500,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map(new Func1<OnTextChangeEvent, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(OnTextChangeEvent event) {
                    CharSequence amount = event.text();
                    return isValid(amount);
                }
            });

formChangeSubscription = amountValidObservable.subscribe(new Action1<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Boolean isValid) {
                amountLayout.setErrorEnabled(isValid ? false : true);
                amountLayout.setError(isValid ? null : "Please enter amount within the range");
            }
        });

        amountValidObservable.subscribe(new Subscriber<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                log.debug("formChangeObservable completed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                log.debug("formChangeObservable error!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Boolean formValid) {
                           nextBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn);
                nextBtn.setEnabled(formValid);
            }
        });
```

I want to format the text of the edit text using something like

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("$#,###");
```

How can I format text using this formatter with RxJava as the user is typing. Please Note, Due to some dependency I cannot use RxBindings yet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you have 2 subscribers to 1 Observable, so would be good to refCunt it! Just add `.replay(1).refCount()` at the end of `amountValidObervable` So it will be:

```
WidgetObservable.text(amount, false)
        .debounce(500,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .map(new Func1<OnTextChangeEvent, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call(OnTextChangeEvent event) {
                CharSequence amount = event.text();
                return isValid(amount);
            }
        })
        .replay(1)
        .refCount();
```